# Transferring project to another account

Tags: firebase

Firebase went to huge update and now I have to update my apps as well. I created projects and later apps with one email (this is my backup email). And I use AdMob for monetisation but with another email (this is my main email). I set my billing and everything in AdMob so it is impossible to connect project with AdMob when project is associated with one account and AdMob with another.

Is there some (easy) way to transfer my project to another account (which uses my main email) so I can sync all services?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add your other account as an Owner to your project.

1. Go to https://console.firebase.google.com
2. Select your project
3. Go to the cog icon in the left nav
4. Select *Permissions*
5. Press *ADD MEMBER*
6. Set role to *Project > Owner*

[image: The permissions link in the Firebase Console]

Your other account should get an invite, and then get access!